# Escape $ sign in Playbook Variable

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook using the URI module to handle provisioning through REST API calls.

To get authenticated to the API, I'm requesting an Authorization token like most REST API's work.

When the returned token has a '$' character, it is escaped therefore my playbook fails as the authorization is rejected.

I'm able to reproduce without the URI module:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts -e IPAM_TOKEN="Hj6E5HsSZ$LLQFlmMkhtTW6f" IPAM/b2b_global_alloc_dual_cpe.yml

PLAY [Playbook to allocate B2B Global Subnet from IPAM on Dual CPE] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Test] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Hj6E5HsSZ"
}
```

I've tried to add the Jinja safe filter in my variable but still '$' character is escaped somehow:

```
- name: Test
    debug:
        msg: "{{ IPAM_TOKEN | safe }}"
```

Any suggestion ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to escape the `$` character when you are invoking the playbook and passing in CLI arguements.
Try running this:
`ansible-playbook -i hosts -e IPAM_TOKEN="Hj6E5HsSZ\$LLQFlmMkhtTW6f" IPAM/b2b_global_alloc_dual_cpe.yml`
I also tested uri module and it doesn't seem to do anything to the dollar sign.

Answer (score 2):

Test with the URI module:

```
---
- name: Retry url until xml content equals certain value
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Retrieve token
      uri:
          url: "https://httpbin.org/anything"
          method: POST
          timeout: 10
          validate_certs: no
          headers:
            token: "Hj6E5HsSZ$LLQFlmMkhtTW6f"
      register: token_response_body

    - name: debug token_response_body
      debug: var=token_response_body.json.headers.Token
...
```

Output:

```
TASK [debug token_response_body] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "token_response_body.json.headers.Token": "Hj6E5HsSZ$LLQFlmMkhtTW6f"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Anant. Issue was when passing the variable value via shell.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think the '$' is escaped by the shell before Ansible playbook gets a chance to see it.

The following works:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts -e IPAM_TOKEN="Hj6E5HsSZ\$LLQFlmMkhtTW6f" IPAM/b2b_global_alloc_dual_cpe.yml

    PLAY [Playbook to allocate B2B Global Subnet from IPAM on Dual CPE] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************

    TASK [Test] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
    ok: [localhost] => {
        "msg": "Hj6E5HsSZ$LLQFlmMkhtTW6f"
    }
```

Comment: If you use single quotes in the shell, you shouldn't have to escape the $ sign: `IPAM_TOKEN='Hj6E5HsSZ$LLQFlmMkhtTW6f'`. Bash is evaluating variables in double-quoted strings, but not in ones that are single-quoted.